# Get the mean across list of dataframes by rows

Tags: r, list, dataframe, aggregate, lapply

I have a list of dataframes and I want to calculate a mean from each first rows, for all second rows etc.

I think this is possible by creating some common factor as index, put dataframes together using `rbind` and then calculate the mean value using `aggregate(value ~ row.index, mean, large.df)`. However, I guess there is more straightforward way?

Here is my example:

```
df1 = data.frame(val = c(4,1,0))
df2 = data.frame(val = c(5,2,1))
df3 = data.frame(val = c(6,3,2))

myLs=list(df1, df2, df3)

[[1]]
  val
1   4
2   1
3   0

[[2]]
  val
1   5
2   2
3   1

[[3]]
  val
1   6
2   3
3   2
```

And my expected dataframe output, as rowise means:

```
df.means
  mean
1   5
2   2
3   1
```

My first steps, not working as expected yet:

```
# Calculate the mean of list by rows
lapply(myLs, function(x) mean(x[1,]))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A simple way would be to `cbind` the list and calculate mean of each row with `rowMeans`

```
rowMeans(do.call(cbind, myLs))
#[1] 5 2 1
```

We can also use `bind_cols` from `dplyr` to combine all the dataframes.

```
rowMeans(dplyr::bind_cols(myLs))
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is another base R solution using `unlist` + `data.frame` + `rowMeans`, i.e.,

```
rowMeans(data.frame(unlist(myLs,recursive = F)))
# [1] 5 2 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Using double loop:

```
sapply(1:3, function(i) mean(sapply(myLs, function(j) j[i, ] )))
# [1] 5 2 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Another `base R` possibility could be:

```
Reduce("+", myLs)/length(myLs)

  val
1   5
2   2
3   1
```